# Can I disable namespace support with XmlReader.Create()?

Tags: c#, .net

At first, I used the first line, but strangely, XPath did not work. After searching Google and read a StackOverflow post, I have found that it is related to namespace. There were answers but one was passing namespace manager or something for each select method, which seemed to complicate the code, and another one was creating an XmlTextReader with namespace disabled (like the second line). But Microsoft says use `Create` instead of creating it directly. How can I disable namespace with `Create` (the first line)?

```
//var r = XmlReader.Create(path); <-- Xpath does not work.
var r = new XmlTextReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) { Namespaces = false }; //<-- Xpath works, but I am using XmlTextReader directly.
var doc = new XmlDocument();

while (r.Read())
{
    if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && r.Name == "item")
    {
        var str = r.ReadOuterXml();
        doc.LoadXml(str);
        var tn = doc.SelectSingleNode("//itemname");
    }
}
```

I use a combination of XmlReader and XmlDocument, because the XML is very large, and extracting information is a lot easier with XmlDocument.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to say with "disable namespace", but you can't instantiate the XmlReader because it's an abstract class. You need an implementation of it, like XmlTextReader, or use the Create method. Take a look at the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The problem is that using the first line (commented out) instead of the second line, makes the Xpath not work. The problem is related to namespace.

Comment: Maybe some configuration in the XmlReaderSettings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You already posted code that does what you ask. What is the question? Why don't you just set the `XmlTextReader.Namespaces` property to false? That's what the object initializer syntax does. Set properties *after* the constructor returns a valid object

Comment: You do know the right thing to do here is to *work with namespaces* rather than trying to disable them, don't you?

Comment: The question was achieving the same result without knowing it is an XmlTextReader. The second line works, so it is not that I am very desperate about it, but I just wondered if there is a better way. And I did not know it was the right thing to do to work with namespaces, because in this case I did not need it. But... if it is the right thing, I will refer to the other question I had mentioned, and use the way that deals with namespace. Can I close my own question?